# How can I get my cat to stop chewing the whiskers off his sibling?

Tags: cats, chewing

I have two older kittens, about 8 months now. A boy and a girl, both done. They were the only two in the litter and they are very friendly and loving both to me and each other. They are very close and neither seems particularly to be top-cat, they play, sleep and wash together. However, the boy gets very intense when he washes his sister, and nibbles/chews off all her whiskers. She allows him to do this, in fact seems to be enjoying it, but she now has no whiskers! Why does he do this and how can I stop him? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does "done" mean they've been spayed/neutered (desexed)?

Comment: @Zaralynda  Yes, it does. Do you have any experience with this type of behaviour in cats?

Comment: I just adopted a pair of 2.5 year old Cornish Rex brothers; One of them does this to his brother too.  I'd love to find a way to stop it, but I'm afraid it  is too late to change the behavior now, especially since it is so hard to catch him doing it.

Comment: I know a similar problem where horses chew off other horses long hair (mane, tail). In this case we would use extra hot chili paste to stop them. We just put some into the long hair and the chewing off would soon stop. They don't seem to like the flavour. I do not know that much about cats, but maybe you can think of something similar (and harmless!)?

Answer (score 1):

He may be doing this because he is bored. Try to stimulate his boredom by getting him an interactive treat toy, or you can even make toys out of tinfoil. When he keeps trying to pull off her whiskers, distract his attention by giving him something to play with.